# C++ initializer constantly creating new objects at same memory location

Tags: c++, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

I have a simple recursive-type container object "Level" (such as a directory, which can contain multiples of itself), although I'm not sure that's related to this problem.

```
//Level.h
class Level
{

public:

    Level();
    vector<Level*> SubLevels;
    Level CreateSubLevel();
}

//Level.cpp
Level::Level()
{
    SubLevels = vector<Level*>();
}

Level Level::CreateSubLevel()
{
    Level NewLevel = Level();

    SubLevels.push_back(&NewLevel);

    return NewLevel;
}
```

If then in my main loop I call

```
//main.cpp
Level MasterLevel = Level();
MasterLevel.CreateSubLevel();
MasterLevel.CreateSubLevel();
MasterLevel.CreateSubLevel();
```

I find that indeed the vector MasterLevel.SubLevels contains three pointers to Level objects. However, they are all pointers to the same address!

I'm not sure why this is happening. My memory management skills are lacking - but I'm suspecting that it's because every time CreateSubLevel() is called, a new object is created, but then it is deleted when CreateSubLevel() exits? I thought that ARC would keep track of the fact that the pointer to it still exists, but perhaps I'm mistaken? Or is it another issue entirely?

How can I best fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You're pushing the address of a temporary object... `NewLevel` no longer exists when you return, it gets *copied* to a new instance but the address you just pushed back is invalid.

Comment: Huh, ok, I thought that might be the case. Is there an ideal solution to this then? Would changing the vector to store objects instead of pointers fix the problem?

Comment: @StuartBarth Yes having values instead of pointers is probably preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SubLevels` is holding onto three pointers to temporaries. It's not a surprise that the compiler chose to reuse the same memory for the temporary each time - why not?

If you want to actually store three different `Level`s correctly, you will either have to store them by value:

```
vector<Level> SubLevels;
SubLevels.push_back(Level());
```

Or actually allocate `Level`s:

```
vector<Level*> SubLevels;
SubLevels.push_back(new Level); // don't forget to delete!
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Guess I still have some to learn about allocation!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you come up with the same value every time is because you are using the address of a temporary variable (on the stack). Every time the function `CreateSubLevel()` is called, the stack is reused, thus the objects are stored in the same location every call.

You can allocate objects on the heap using `operator new()`:

```
vector<Level*> SubLevels;
SubLevels.push_back(new Level);
```

Then you can `delete` them in a destructor:

```
Level::~Level()
{
    vector<Level*>::iterator i;
    for (i = SubLevels.begin(); i != SubLevels.end(); ++i)
        delete *i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three calls to `MasterLevel.CreateSubLevel();` one after the other. Each call creates a stack frame that is of the same size. Hence, the address of the local variable is the same. You are storing the address of the local variable in `SubLevels`.

If you use the address stored in `SubLevels`, you will run into undefined behavior. You need to allocate memory from heap.

While you are at it, keep a list of smart pointers, `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead of storing raw pointers.

Use

```
vector<std::shared_ptr<Level>> SubLevels;
```

and use it as:

```
void Level::CreateSubLevel()
{
    SubLevels.push_back(std::make_shared<Level>());
}
```